# Iso Message trailer issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, iso8583

I have a iso message with header and trailer like **02 ..iso message.. 03d858**
Using base24 channel I can able to produce header and trailer 03 I need d858 value to be added in trailer and while using base24 channel I'm getting message too long exception.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the exception you are getting? Is that when receiving the response? What happens on the server when you send it, if the channel is wrong, are you sure the server is understanding the request?

Comment: Hi AndrésAlcarraz thanks for the response.
Server is not accepting the iso message from jmeter since the trailer is not having D858

I have tried with other channel but other than base24 channel no other channel is adding trailer to my message

Comment: You will have to use a custom channel for that, one that you will have to implement, but that trailer is supposed to be constant?

Comment: Ok can you give me any blog regarding this

Comment: I don't know any, about configuring that specifically for jmeter. I can try to post an answer, provided you give more details, like the stack trace of the exception in the server, and if that trailer is supposed to be constant.